# heroku deployment error ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm using ruby on rails 3.2 and added a jquery based calendar, i worked until I added this calendar. I don't understand whats the problem. The error is the typical: We're sorry, but something went wrong.

```
     2013-05-30T16:24:23.120911+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-05-30 16:24:23] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-05-30T16:24:23.121177+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-05-30 16:24:23] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-05-30T16:24:23.121720+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-05-30 16:24:23] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=37427
2013-05-30T16:24:23.150350+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-05-30T16:24:25.380808+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-05-30T16:24:25.380614+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-05-30T16:24:27.414530+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-05-30T16:24:29.609472+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-05-30T16:24:29.609472+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.12 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:37427
2013-05-30T16:24:29.609472+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 146.155.157.11 at 2013-05-30 16:24:29 +0000
2013-05-30T16:24:29.609472+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-05-30T16:24:29.609472+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-05-30T16:24:30.091675+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=clinicaua.herokuapp.com fwd="146.155.157.11" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=499ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-05-30T16:24:30.081632+00:00 app[web.1]:     27:     <!-- Size should be 114 x 114 pixels -->
2013-05-30T16:24:30.081632+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:24:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3338499994553736987_38308120'
2013-05-30T16:24:30.082010+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-30T16:24:30.082010+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-30T16:24:30.082010+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2013-05-30T16:24:30.082010+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (13.3ms)
2013-05-30T16:24:30.081632+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (images/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png isn't precompiled):
2013-05-30T16:24:30.081632+00:00 app[web.1]:     21: 
2013-05-30T16:24:30.081632+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:     <!-- For third-generation iPad with high-resolution Retina display: -->
2013-05-30T16:24:30.081632+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:     <!-- Size should be 144 x 144 pixels -->
2013-05-30T16:24:30.081632+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:     <%= favicon_link_tag 'images/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png', :rel => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed', :type => 'image/png', :sizes => '144x144' %>
2013-05-30T16:24:30.081632+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-30T16:24:30.081632+00:00 app[web.1]:     25: 
2013-05-30T16:24:30.081632+00:00 app[web.1]:     26:     <!-- For iPhone with high-resolution Retina display: -->
2013-05-30T16:24:30.082010+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 116ms
2013-05-30T16:24:30.417307+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=clinicaua.herokuapp.com fwd="146.155.157.11" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not precompiled jquery-ui.

There are several ways to do that, this is one:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.precompile << 'jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js'
```

Or you could use https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails